# Runge Kutta terminate when condition reached

Tags: c#, ode, runge-kutta

The bouncing ball example shown in the Matlab ODE Solver has a way to terminate integration when an even triggers (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ode-event-location.html).  In this example it terminates when height is 0.  You could also terminate when the slope changes from positive to negative (apex of ball flight) or negative to positive (when ball hits the floor).

Is there a way to implement this kind of triggering in Math.Net RungeKutta.FourthOrder() ?

Also, is there better documentation anywhere besides the tests and class reference?  The information there is pretty thin https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.OdeSolvers/RungeKutta.htm#FourthOrder.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The principal idea is to check every integration step if there is a root in the current segment. To facilitate that an interpolating polynomial for the solution is used, the so-called `dense output`. This is inserted into the event function and then an ordinary root finding procedure is used for this composite function, usually starting with sampling the interval to look for sign changes, then refining the root via some method with a bracketing interval.

For RK4 there exists a cubic interpolation polynomial constructed from the values of the stages. This gives results of middling quality, better than just the secant, but not the full 4th or 5th order of the step error.

Using `dy=(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6` and `k1,k2,k3,k4` from the step computation,
the interpolated value `y` at `t` between `t0` and `t1=t0+h` is obtained as

```
s = (t-t0)/h
y = y0+s*(3*(1-s)**2+s**2)*dy + s*(1-s)/2*(k1-2*(1-2*s)*(k2+k3)-k4)
```